# cannot load a json file in python (json discord.py)

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

when i try to load a json file this error happens : `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 5 (char 6)`

code:

```py
with open("users.json") as fp:
    users = json.load(fp)
```

i want to load a json file called 'users' for my leveling system can someone help please .

full leveling system code :

```py
try:
    with open("users.json") as fp:
        users = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    users = {}


def save_users():
    with open("users.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=int(4))

def add_points(user: discord.User, points: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in users:
        users[id] = {}
    users[id]["points"] = users[id].get("points", 0) + points
    print("{} now has {} points".format(user.name, users[id]["points"]))
    save_users()

def get_points(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in users:
        return users[id].get("points", 0)
    return 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    print("{} sent a message".format(message.author.name))
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!points"):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="You have {} Global Points!".format(get_points(message.author)),
                    color=0x0061ff)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!rank"):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="You have {} Global Points!".format(get_points(message.author)),
                    color=0x0061ff)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    add_points(message.author, 1)
```

and i tryed this one :

```py
with open("users.json") as fp:
    users = json.load(fp)



def save_users():
    with open("users.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=int(4))

def add_points(user: discord.User, points: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in users:
        users[id] = {}
    users[id]["points"] = users[id].get("points", 0) + points
    print("{} now has {} points".format(user.name, users[id]["points"]))
    save_users()

def get_points(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in users:
        return users[id].get("points", 0)
    return 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    print("{} sent a message".format(message.author.name))
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!points"):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="You have {} Global Points!".format(get_points(message.author)),
                    color=0x0061ff)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!rank"):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="You have {} Global Points!".format(get_points(message.author)),
                    color=0x0061ff)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    add_points(message.author, 1)
```

Comment: The error is in the json file, not in the code. You can use a tool to validate the json content, such https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should check that json file's how true because if strings is wrong you may encounter errors

if json file path is not the same as your path your code should be like this : `with open("path\\users.json") as fp:`

Comment: it is in the same path but tank you

Answer (score 0):

JSON files have to be of the following format:

```
{"key-1": "value-1", "key-2": "value-2"}
```

You are getting this error because you are using this:

```
{'key-1': 'value-1', 'key-2': 'value-2'}
```

You can fix your JSON dumping code:

```py
def save_users():
    with open("users.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(str(users).replace("'", '"'), fp, sort_keys=True, indent=int(4))
```